# Points of a set that are not included in an open cover of its set of limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My conjecture is the following:

Given a bounded set $S\subset \mathbb{R}$, its set of limit points $S'$ and some collection of open sets $\{U_\alpha\}_{a\in A}$ such that $S' \subset \bigcup_{a\in A}U_a$, the set $S\setminus \left[\bigcup_{a\in A}U_a\right]$ should be finite.

There is probably an easy solution out there but I'm not good at this and I can't find anything online. If this is not the case, is there another hypothesis we can add to make this true?

Comment: What do you mean by limited set?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I meant bounded set, translated it wrong from my language.

Comment: What if $S = (0,1)$ and  $U_1 = (-0.1,0.1)$ and $U_2= (0.9,1.1)$? Then  $S' = \{0, 1\}$  and $S'\subset \cup_{i\in \{1,2\}} U_1$ and  $S\setminus [\cup_{i\in \{1,2\}} U_i] = [0.1, 0.9]$.  That is not finite.

Comment: @fleablood what u denote b $S'$ is the boundary not the set of limit points.The set of limit points is $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$

Comment: Dope slap to me.  *COOOOOOOFFFFEEEE*

Comment: Your claim is correct. Say $S\cup S' \subset [-M,M]$. Then $[-M,M]\setminus [\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} U_{\alpha}]$ is closed and bounded, hence compact.
Now if $S\setminus [\bigcup U_{\alpha}]$ is infinite, we know that every infinite set in a compact set has a limit point, which contradicts the fact that $S'\subset \bigcup U_{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjecture is true.

Assume to the contrary  that $D=S\setminus \left[\bigcup_{a\in A}U_a\right]$ is infinite. Since $S$ is bounded, so is this set $D$. That means it has a limit point $l$. Since $D \subseteq S$, we have $l \in S'$. That means there is an index $a_0 \in A$, such that $l \in U_{a_0}$. Since $U_{a_0}$ is open, it means there exists a $\epsilon >0$ such that $(l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon) \subseteq U_{a_0}$.

However that means that all points in $S\setminus U_{a_0}$ have distance at least $\epsilon$ from $l$. Since $D=S\setminus \left[\bigcup_{a\in A}U_a\right] \subseteq S\setminus U_{a_0}$, that is also true for $D$, which means that $l$ cannot be a limit point of $D$. This is a contradiction.